# Why the html page doesn't get showed in thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm using `spring boot` and the `thymeleaf` view engine.

The problem is the controller doesn't show the proper html page and always shows the `Whitelabel Error Page`.

The controller:

```
package com.example.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


@Controller
public class GifController {

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public String sayhello() {
        return "greets";
    }
}
```

The greets.html file in resources/templates path:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello!
</body>
</html>
```

also:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And the pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Where's the problem? When I browse to `localhost:8080/greeting` it shows `whitelabel Error page` instead of the `greets.html`.

Comment: I have your same problem, did you solved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Controller and SpringBoot application looks ok. Try to clean and build your project. When you will run DemoApplication you should see like below in console

```
Mapped "{[/greeting]}" onto public java.lang.String com.example.controller.GifController.sayhello()
```

And in your DemoApplication you only need @SpringBootApplication as this annotation is equivalent to using @Configuration, @EnableAutoConfiguration and @ComponentScan

Comment: I tested your code and it is working for me. Try to add index.html in templates folder and  one more method in GifController  like @RequestMapping("/")
    public String hello() {
        return "index";
    }. Try to clean, package your project and test it.

Answer (score 0):

I am just a spring-boot learner and trying to learn it by resolving your issue.

I made few changes i created a Config class and put some configuration in it

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        return resolver;
    }
}



@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Also i put greet.html page in /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/templates/greet.html
i like to put html/jsp pages into that location you can use your own location and just replace that location in Config.java class
    @Controller
    public class GifController {

```
    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public String sayhello() {
        return "greets";
    }
}
```

try these changes and than see if you are able to see output on browser or not.

Comment: Could you please share imports or share complete file ?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same white label error. Took me couple of hours to figure out that actually thymeleaf dependency wasn't getting resolved properly. The solution was pretty simple and silly both.

1. Stop tomcat.
2. Right click on the project.
3. Gradle -> Refresh gradle project (Or similar step for maven)
4. Start tomcat.
5. If that doesn't work, change the position of below line in build.gradle (move up or down), and perform above steps.

   compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')

For maven, in pom.xml

`<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>`

The important part is, you have to gradle refresh your project while tomcat is NOT running. If we use devtools, we depend on it blindly for restarting our servlet container and stuffs, but sometimes a manual start stop comes handy.