# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: error after adding new repository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Hello im trying to work on a project first of all it was all smooth when i worked on a single model as you see below "Student"

> **StudentController**

```
package net.springboot.javaguides.controller;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import net.springboot.javaguides.entity.Student;
import net.springboot.javaguides.repository.StudentRepository;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/students/")
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;    
    
    @GetMapping("showForm")
    public String showStudentForm(Student student) {
        return "student/add-student";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("list")
    public String students(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("students", this.studentRepository.findAll());
        return "student/index";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("add")
    public String addStudent(@Valid Student student, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return "student/add-student";
        }
        
        this.studentRepository.save(student);
        return "redirect:list";
    }
    
    
    @GetMapping("edit/{id}")
    public String showUpdateForm(@PathVariable ("id") long id, Model model) {
        Student student = this.studentRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid student id : " + id));
        
        model.addAttribute("student", student);
        return "student/update-student";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("update/{id}")
    public String updateStudent(@PathVariable("id") long id, @Valid Student student, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            student.setId(id);
            return "student/update-student";
        }
        
        // update student
        studentRepository.save(student);
        
        // get all students ( with update)
        model.addAttribute("students", this.studentRepository.findAll());
        return "student/index";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("delete/{id}")
    public String deleteStudent(@PathVariable ("id") long id, Model model) {
        
        Student student = this.studentRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid student id : " + id));
        
        this.studentRepository.delete(student);
        model.addAttribute("students", this.studentRepository.findAll());
        return "student/index";
        
    }
}
```

> **StudentEntity**

```
package net.springboot.javaguides.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Student {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    
    @Column(name = "phone_no")
    private long phoneNo;
    
    
    public Student() {
        super();
    }

    public Student(String name, String email) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }
    
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public long getPhoneNo() {
        return phoneNo;
    }
    public void setPhoneNo(long phoneNo) {
        this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
    }
}
```

> **StudentRepository**

```
package net.springboot.javaguides.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import net.springboot.javaguides.entity.Student;

@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long>{
    List<Student> findByName(String name);
}
```

and now im trying to add some new model as you see below but im having error from it :

> **CourseController**

```
package net.springboot.javaguides.controller;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import net.springboot.javaguides.entity.Course;
import net.springboot.javaguides.repository.CourseRepository;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/courses/")
public class CourseController {

    @Autowired
    private CourseRepository courseRepository;  
    
    @GetMapping("showForm")
    public String showCourseForm(Course course) {
        return "add-course";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("list")
    public String courses(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("courses", this.courseRepository.findAll());
        return "index";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("add")
    public String addCourse(@Valid Course course, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return "add-course";
        }
        
        this.courseRepository.save(course);
        return "redirect:list";
    }
    
    
    @GetMapping("edit/{id}")
    public String showUpdateForm(@PathVariable ("id") long id, Model model) {
        Course course = this.courseRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid course id : " + id));
        
        model.addAttribute("course", course);
        return "update-course";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("update/{id}")
    public String updateCourse(@PathVariable("id") long id, @Valid Course course, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            course.setId(id);
            return "update-course";
        }
        
        // update course
        courseRepository.save(course);
        
        // get all courses ( with update)
        model.addAttribute("courses", this.courseRepository.findAll());
        return "index";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("delete/{id}")
    public String deleteCourse(@PathVariable ("id") long id, Model model) {
        
        Course course = this.courseRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid course id : " + id));
        
        this.courseRepository.delete(course);
        model.addAttribute("courses", this.courseRepository.findAll());
        return "index";
        
    }
}
```

> **CourseEntity**

```
package net.springboot.javaguides.entity;


import java.sql.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Courses")
public class Course {
    
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private Long id;
    
        @Column(name = "cours_name")
     private String cours_name;
     
        @Column(name = "date_debut")
     private Date date_debut;
     
        @Column(name = "date_fin")
     private Date date_fin;
     
        @Column(name = "enseignant")
     private String enseignant;
     
        @Column(name = "type_cours")
     private String type_cours;
     
        @Column(name = "filliere")
     private String filliere;
    
     public Course() {
         super();
     }
     
     public Course(String cours_name, Date date_debut, Date date_fin, String enseignant, String type_cours,
            String filliere) {
        super();
        this.cours_name = cours_name;
        this.date_debut = date_debut;
        this.date_fin = date_fin;
        this.enseignant = enseignant;
        this.type_cours = type_cours;
        this.filliere = filliere;
    }
        
     
     public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getCours_name() {
        return cours_name;
    }

    public void setCours_name(String cours_name) {
        this.cours_name = cours_name;
    }

    public Date getDate_debut() {
        return date_debut;
    }

    public void setDate_debut(Date date_debut) {
        this.date_debut = date_debut;
    }

    public Date getDate_fin() {
        return date_fin;
    }

    public void setDate_fin(Date date_fin) {
        this.date_fin = date_fin;
    }

    public String getEnseignant() {
        return enseignant;
    }

    public void setEnseignant(String enseignant) {
        this.enseignant = enseignant;
    }

    public String getType_cours() {
        return type_cours;
    }

    public void setType_cours(String type_cours) {
        this.type_cours = type_cours;
    }

    public String getfilliere() {
        return filliere;
    }

    public void setfilliere(String filliere) {
        this.filliere = filliere;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    
     
}
```

**

> CourseRepository

**

```
package net.springboot.javaguides.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import net.springboot.javaguides.entity.Course;

@Repository
public interface CourseRepository extends JpaRepository<Course, Long>{
    List<Course> findByName(String cours_name);
}
```

but im having this error

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.0.RELEASE)

2020-08-27 13:44:03.876  INFO 9188 --- [  restartedMain] s.j.SpringbootThymeleafWebAppApplication : Starting SpringbootThymeleafWebAppApplication on DESKTOP-5D7IMCJ with PID 9188 (C:\Users\yassi\Desktop\workspacenew\springboot-thymeleaf-web-app-master\target\classes started by yassi in C:\Users\yassi\Desktop\workspacenew\springboot-thymeleaf-web-app-master)
2020-08-27 13:44:03.880  INFO 9188 --- [  restartedMain] s.j.SpringbootThymeleafWebAppApplication : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-08-27 13:44:03.941  INFO 9188 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2020-08-27 13:44:03.941  INFO 9188 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2020-08-27 13:44:04.881  INFO 9188 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-08-27 13:44:04.957  INFO 9188 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 68ms. Found 2 repository interfaces.
2020-08-27 13:44:05.415  INFO 9188 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$97fbb782] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-08-27 13:44:05.849  INFO 9188 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-08-27 13:44:05.868  INFO 9188 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-08-27 13:44:05.868  INFO 9188 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.12
2020-08-27 13:44:05.876  INFO 9188 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_221\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_221/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_221/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_221/lib/amd64;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin;C:\Users\yassi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\yassi\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;D:\eclipse;;.]
2020-08-27 13:44:05.990  INFO 9188 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-08-27 13:44:05.990  INFO 9188 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2049 ms
2020-08-27 13:44:06.025  INFO 9188 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2020-08-27 13:44:06.031  INFO 9188 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2020-08-27 13:44:06.031  INFO 9188 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2020-08-27 13:44:06.031  INFO 9188 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'formContentFilter' to: [/*]
2020-08-27 13:44:06.031  INFO 9188 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2020-08-27 13:44:06.203  INFO 9188 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-08-27 13:44:06.332  INFO 9188 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-08-27 13:44:06.388  INFO 9188 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2020-08-27 13:44:06.630  INFO 9188 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.7.Final}
2020-08-27 13:44:06.632  INFO 9188 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2020-08-27 13:44:06.776  INFO 9188 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2020-08-27 13:44:06.917  INFO 9188 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
2020-08-27 13:44:07.829  INFO 9188 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-08-27 13:44:07.871  INFO 9188 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2020-08-27 13:44:08.146  WARN 9188 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'courseController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'courseRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'courseRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List net.springboot.javaguides.repository.CourseRepository.findByName(java.lang.String)! No property name found for type Course!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log says the problem already! .repository.CourseRepository.findByName(java.lang.String)! No property name found for type Course! Your Course entity doesn't have a property called name, it's called cours_name. Change the cours_name in your Course entity to name or change the name of the method in CourseRepository!

Comment: I have already changed the name of the method in CourseRepository to cours_name but it gives me the same error i guess there is a cache on it or something

Comment: Cache will reset when you stop and run the project again. Restart it, try the solution and then send the new log please

Comment: it does work now, but it gives me error 404 at localhost:8080 because now i want to give it differents routes for url localhost:8080/students and localhost:8080/courses.
under templates i have 2 subfolders one for courses pages html "add/index/update" and another for students and i work with thymleaf. basically it was working under root directly before adding courses classes
 i appreaciate your help .

Comment: That's another problem. I think you should ask another question for that. And please accept and upvote the answer. Thanks ;)

Comment: its because i can't right now ! i need to wait 2 days and today is my last deadline for this ! thanks anyway

Comment: Ok I see. Now you have a routing problem right? You only use Thymeleaf on the front-end? Can you explain what you're doing, share the console log etc. exactly?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52505514/spring-boot-404-when-trying-to-load-a-html-file-using-thymeleaf/52507133 and https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-in-spring-mvc Be sure that your configuration and project folder structure etc. is ok!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `@EnableJpaRepositories(packages)` on top of your main class.

i had an same issue, i handled with adding @EntityScan or @EnableJpaRepositories(packages)

Comment: above @SpringBootApplication ? btw i deleted (packages) i did it but it doesnt work unfortunately

Comment: Yes, try EntityScan or component scan as well.

Comment: i tried it but ive got another error 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'courseController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'courseRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'net.springboot.javaguides.repository.CourseRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}